# Matching only part of object name

Tags: vba, excel

How do I make the following code work with a table with a a different number in its name, for example MarketsBudgetOverviewTable8 or MarketsBudgetOverviewTable21?

```
With current_sheet
    .ListObjects("MarketsBudgetOverviewTable6").ListColumns("OBP 2018"). _
        TotalsCalculation = xlTotalsCalculationSum 
End with
```

Comment: Do you know ahead of time what these numbers will be? Are you trying to loop through all tables (in which case looping through the objects might be easier)?

Comment: (I assume wildcards don't work?)  Perhaps loop through listobjects, checking something like if the listobject name is like "marketsBudget" then store that name as a variable and use it?

Comment: did you tried wildcard * after MarketsBudgetOverviewTable

Comment: Will there be more than one per sheet, as you can use the index number of the listobject possibly?  Or wrap it in a function, like `fnListObjects(lo as listobject)` then use `lo` in your code???

Comment: I used a loop as suggested by BruceWayne solution and it worked. And no, wildcards don't work. Thanks all

Comment: Why not just name your tables property instead? What's in `Table8` that's not in `Table21`? Why would you look at `Table6` rather than `Table42`? These numbers look like the original table was copied over but never renamed for some reason.